# Fragment Loader not showing data in ListView

Tags: listview, fragment, loader

I have implemented my own Loader and trying to use it in a Fragment.

I know the ContentProvider code is working, because I have tracked it with LOG messages. The error must be in my Fragment code.

Can someone, more experienced than me, please spot the deliberate mistake.

```
 public class StorePickerFragment extends ListFragment implements
 LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


 private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

 /** Called when the Fragment is first created. */
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
fillData();
 // Inflate the layout for this fragment


 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_list, container, false);
 }


 private void fillData() {

 // Fields from the database (projection)
 // Must include the _id column for the adapter to work
 String[] from = new String[] {StoreTable.COLUMN_ID, StoreTable.COLUMN_NAME };
 // Fields on the UI to which we map
 int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label };


 getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
 adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.store_row, null, from,
 to, 0);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
 }


 // Creates a new loader after the initLoader () call
 @Override
 public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
 String[] projection = { StoreTable.COLUMN_ID, StoreTable.COLUMN_NAME };
 CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
    MyContentProvider.STORE_URI, projection,null,null, StoreTable.COLUMN_NAME);
 return cursorLoader;
 }

 @Override
 public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
 adapter.swapCursor(data);
 }

 @Override
 public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
 // data is not available anymore, delete reference
 adapter.swapCursor(null);
 }

 }
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is following this question, fear not, there is nothing fatally wrong with the code. The style may well be able to be corrected but the reason for not displaying any data was because the dataset was empty.

Comment: Unfortunately, when converting from Activity to Fragment, I forgot to include the code which loaded dummy data into the database !